# probems with <link rel=preload>` on my wordpress site

Tags: html

I want to preload the file on my site but the following code does not work what am I doing wrong?

```
<link rel="preload" href="wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/icons/fl-icons.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Needs more details: How is it not working? Is there an error? What outcome are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you missed "/".

`<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content ...`